# Metpy mpcalc.absolute_vorticity() with incompatible grids

Tags: python, metpy

I'm attempting to follow [this training example](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/MetPy_Advanced/qg-analysis/) to calculate QG omega on NCEP/NCAR data but I'm getting hung up on mpcalc.absolute_vorticity.

```
import xarray as xr
import metpy.calc as mc
import metpy.constants as mpconstants
from metpy.units import units
import numpy as np

path='./'
uf = 'uwnd.2018.nc'
vf = 'vwnd.2018.nc'
af = 'air.2018.nc'

ads = xr.open_dataset(path+af).metpy.parse_cf()
uds = xr.open_dataset(path+uf).metpy.parse_cf()
vds = xr.open_dataset(path+vf).metpy.parse_cf()

a700 = ads['air'].metpy.sel(
        level=700 * units.hPa,
        time='2018-01-04T12')
u700 = uds['uwnd'].metpy.sel(
        level=700 * units.hPa,
        time='2018-01-04T12')
v700 = vds['vwnd'].metpy.sel(
        level=700 * units.hPa,
        time='2018-01-04T12')

lats = ads['lat'].metpy.unit_array
lons = ads['lon'].metpy.unit_array
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
dx, dy = mc.lat_lon_grid_deltas(lons,lats)

avort = mc.absolute_vorticity(u700,v700,dx,dy,lats)
```

I get the error, "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (73,144) (73,) ".

Full error traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metpy.decomp.py", line 43, in <module>
    avort = mc.absolute_vorticity(u700,v700,dx,dy,lats) 
  File "/work1/jsa/anconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 570, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/work1/jsa/anconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/metpy/units.py", line 312, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/work1/jsa/anconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/metpy/calc/kinematics.py", line 639, in absolute_vorticity
    return relative_vorticity + f
  File "/work1/jsa/anconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 754, in __add__
    return self._add_sub(other, operator.add)
  File "/work1/jsa/anconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 75, in wrapped
    result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/work1/jsa/anconda3/envs/earth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 686, in _add_sub
    magnitude = op(self._magnitude, other._magnitude)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (73,144) (73,)
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to see the full error traceback and not just the last error so that the failing line can actually be seen.

Comment: Apologies for not including originally, the full error traceback is now included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to the data or the full error, my guess is the problem is that lats doesn't have the right shape to obey NumPy's [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules). Try changing to:

```
avort = mc.absolute_vorticity(u700, v700, dx, dy, lats[:, None])
```

Essentially, the trailing dimensions need to line up. Before, NumPy was trying to line up 73 (lats) with the lons dimension (144). Adding the `[:, None]` creates a size-1 dimension as the last dimension for lats, and then the alignment is trying to match shape (73, 1) with (73, 144), which works.